# simulate WebCrypto RSA-OAEP encryption in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, rsa, phpseclib, webcrypto-api

We have a server which is using RSA-OAEP to receive data from client.

I don't have access to server and the only way to check my result is to send a request and check its reply.

I've been able to send correct request with WebCrypto but I didn't have any success with php.

the code I'm using for JS :

```
var DataToEncrypt = 'abcd';
var pemEncodedKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;
let encryptionKey;
function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
}

function importPublicKey(pem) {
    const pemHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----";
    const pemFooter = "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    const pemContents = pem.substring(pemHeader.length, pem.length - pemFooter.length);
    const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);

    return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "spki",
        binaryDer,
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP",
            hash: "SHA-256"
        },
        true,
        ["encrypt"]
    );
}

function getMessageEncoding() {
    const enc = new TextEncoder();
    return enc.encode(DataToEncrypt);
}
async function encryptMessage() {
    const encoded = getMessageEncoding();
    const ciphertext = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "RSA-OAEP"
        },
        encryptionKey,
        encoded
    );

    var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf8');
    var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(ciphertext)));
    document.getElementById('crypt').value = b64encoded;
}

document.getElementById('import').addEventListener("click", async () => {
    encryptionKey = await importPublicKey(pemEncodedKey);
});

document.getElementById('encrypt').addEventListener("click", function(){
    encryptMessage();
});
```

and this is my php function (using phpseclib) :

```
function encrypt($data) {
    $key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');
    $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
    $rsa->loadKey($key); // public key
    $crypted = $rsa->encrypt($data);

    return base64_encode($crypted);
}
echo encrypt('abcd');
```

I tried both of these methods result to send a request to server and as I mentioned earlier only js code works and php output does not work as expected.

Comment: Can you post your javascript code in jsfiddle.net in such a way that'll let me reproduce the problem? I made an attempt to adapt your code for use at https://jsfiddle.net/8rgkf536/ and it's not working. Maybe with more effort I could figure it out but maybe it'd take you less effort to get it working in jsfiddle than it'd take me. If you need a public key use the one at https://pastebin.com/XDYkC84K

Comment: the problem is not from js, it's from php output

Comment: I want to be able to produce a ciphertext with the JS and then try to decrypt it with the PHP code. The two ways we can go about doing this are (1) you provide a ciphertext along with a corresponding private key --or-- (2) you provide some JS code that I can use to generate my own ciphertext.

Comment: My thought is that maybe you need to be doing `$rsa->setMGFHash('sha256');` as well in the PHP code but I cannot confirm without ciphertext and the private key. I cannot say, for sure, what the JS code is doing without being able to examine the end result of it's output. If you want firm facts instead of just hypothesis's you need to provide me with what I'm looking for. Or you can hope someone else comes along who'll answer this question!

Comment: Also, in lieu of being able to confirm my `$rsa->setMGFHash('sha256')` I will say that I think there's a good possibility that you're expecting both to produce the same ciphertext. They won't. OAEP employees randomized padding. You could use the same public key / plaintext combo ten times and you'd get ten different ciphertext's. And that's just with the JS code.

Comment: @neubert: There a two hash function parameters for OAEP, which the OAEP specs stupidly refer to as the "Hash" and the "MGFHash". Are you able to discern which of these is being set by the hash option to windows.crypto.subtlekey? phpseclib lets you set each of them.

Comment: @neubert I know OAEP produce different ciphertext everytime and I'm not expecting them to create the same result. I tried to make your jsfiddle to work but it produce an error that I don't know what it means. I'll try your approach on my local and will update here.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk I tried different combinations of Hash and MGFHash in phpseclib too as I didn't know WebCrypto uses which one, but there was no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to encrypt something with js and decrypt it with php (phpseclib) using a pair of public/private keys which I produced and it was successful.

After that I tried to reformat my public key to 64 chars in each line (it was in a single line like the one in js) and used both setHash('sha256') and setMGFHash('sha256') and now my php function works.

new php function :

```
function encrypt($data)
{
    $key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');
    $rsa->setMGFHash('sha256');
    $lk = $rsa->loadKey($key); // public key
    $crypted = $rsa->encrypt($data);
    return base64_encode($crypted);
}
```