# Decrypt using RSA OAEP with SHA256 on PHP

Tags: php, encryption

how to decrypt using RSA OAEP with SHA256 on PHP.?

maybe using some package or manual? I dont know how to use it with PHP.

example logic :

```
openssl base64 -A -d -in $encrypt > $temp.bin
openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -inkey $private -in $temp.bin -out $temp.txt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [simulate WebCrypto RSA-OAEP encryption in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740222/simulate-webcrypto-rsa-oaep-encryption-in-php)

Comment: i have same issue, you can looking on this link [How to Decrypt RSA OAEP with SHA256 using openssl on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67913409/how-to-decrypt-rsa-oaep-with-sha256-using-openssl-on-php).