# "Class name must be a valid object or a string" When Installing PHPSecLib Without Composer

Tags: php, class, rsa, phpseclib

I'm trying to do RSA encryption using PHPSecLib, with a manual install (ie not using Composer).

I'm following these manual installation instructions I found here:
https://davescripts.com/manual-installation-of-phpseclib

And trying to do this example which I located here:
[How to Decrypt RSA OAEP with SHA256 using openssl on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67913409/how-to-decrypt-rsa-oaep-with-sha256-using-openssl-on-php)

My steps I've taken so far:

1. Visited the GitHub repository here: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/3.0
2. Under 'Code' selected 'Download ZIP'.
3. Unzipped the files locally and uploaded the entire 'phpseclib' directory to the server.
4. Created a test script, and troubleshooted multiple layers of includes and use that were needed to get it working.
5. However, at the moment, I'm getting a new error - "Class name must be a valid object or a string" which I don't understand and can't seem to resolve.

My test script is now as follows:

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
  header("Content-Type: text/plain");
  $sIncludePath = get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../inc/phpseclib';
  echo $sIncludePath."\n";
  set_include_path($sIncludePath);

  include('Crypt/Common/AsymmetricKey.php');
  include('Math/BigInteger.php');
  include('Crypt/EC.php');
  include('Crypt/PublicKeyLoader.php');
  include('Crypt/RSA.php');

  use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA;
  use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;

  function rsaEncryptionOaepSha256 ($publicKey, $plaintext) {
    $rsa = PublicKeyLoader::load($publicKey)
        ->withHash('sha256')
        ->withMGFHash('sha256');
    return $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
  }

  function rsaDecryptionOaepSha256 ($privateKey, $ciphertext) {
    $rsa = PublicKeyLoader::load($privateKey)
        ->withHash('sha256')
        ->withMGFHash('sha256');
    return $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);
  }
  
  function loadRsaPrivateKeyPem() {
    // this is a sample key - don't worry !
    return '
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
';
  }

  function loadRsaPublicKeyPem() {
    // this is a sample key - don't worry !
    return '
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8EmWJUZ/Osz4vXtUU2S+
0M4BP9+s423gjMjoX+qP1iCnlcRcFWxthQGN2CWSMZwR/vY9V0un/nsIxhZSWOH9
iKzqUtZD4jt35jqOTeJ3PCSr48JirVDNLet7hRT37Ovfu5iieMN7ZNpkjeIG/CfT
/QQl7R+kO/EnTmL3QjLKQNV/HhEbHS2/44x7PPoHqSqkOvl8GW0qtL39gTLWgAe8
01/w5PmcQ38CKG0oT2gdJmJqIxNmAEHkatYGHcMDtXRBpOhOSdraFj6SmPyHEmLB
ishaq7Jm8NPPNK9QcEQ3q+ERa5M6eM72PpF93g2p5cjKgyzzfoIV09Zb/LJ2aW2g
QwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
';
  }

  function base64Encoding ($input) {
    return base64_encode($input);
  }
  function base64Decoding ($input) {
    return base64_decode($input);
  }

  echo 'RSA 2048 encryption OAEP SHA-256 string' . PHP_EOL;
  $sDataToEncrypt = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  echo 'plaintext: ' . $sDataToEncrypt . PHP_EOL;

  // encryption
  echo PHP_EOL . '* * * encrypt the plaintext with the RSA public key * * *' .PHP_EOL;
  $ciphertextBase64 = base64Encoding(rsaEncryptionOaepSha256(loadRsaPublicKeyPem(), $sDataToEncrypt));
  echo 'ciphertextBase64: ' . $ciphertextBase64 . PHP_EOL;

  // transport the encrypted data to recipient

  // receiving the encrypted data, decryption
  echo PHP_EOL . '* * * decrypt the ciphertext with the RSA private key * * *' .PHP_EOL;
  $ciphertextReceivedBase64 = $ciphertextBase64;
  echo 'ciphertextReceivedBase64: ' . $ciphertextReceivedBase64 . PHP_EOL;
  $decryptedtext = rsaDecryptionOaepSha256(loadRsaPrivateKeyPem(), base64Decoding($ciphertextReceivedBase64));
  echo 'decryptedtext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

However, when I attempt to run this PHP code, I receive the following output which has me stuck:

```
.:/opt/alt/php70/usr/share/pear:../inc/phpseclib
RSA 2048 encryption OAEP SHA-256 string
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

* * * encrypt the plaintext with the RSA public key * * *
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /home/.../inc/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php:182
Stack trace:
#0 /home/.../inc/phpseclib/Crypt/Common/AsymmetricKey.php(143): phpseclib3\Math\BigInteger-&gt;__construct(0)
#1 /home/.../inc/phpseclib/Crypt/Common/AsymmetricKey.php(162): phpseclib3\Crypt\Common\AsymmetricKey::initialize_static_variables()
#2 /home/.../inc/phpseclib/Crypt/PublicKeyLoader.php(45): phpseclib3\Crypt\Common\AsymmetricKey::load('\r\n-----BEGIN PU...', false)
#3 /home/.../main/phpseclibtest.php(19): phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader::load('\r\n-----BEGIN PU...')
#4 /home/.../main/phpseclibtest.php(94): rsaEncryptionOaepSha256('\r\n-----BEGIN PU...', 'The quick brown...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/.../inc/phpseclib/Math/BigInteger.php</b> on line <b>182</b><br />
```

In case it helps, note that the test script is in a separate directory like this:

```
inc
-> phpseclib (the PHPSecLib library with all subdirectories)
main
-> phpseclibtest.php (my test script)
```

The PHP version is 7.0.33, if that makes any difference.

I'd really like to figure out how to get PHPSecLib working. If someone could help me figure out what's going on that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to install phpseclib v3 using the instructions for phpseclib v2. There are two options:

**Option 1: Use PHPSecLib V3 With Composer**

This option requires SSH access on the server.

To install phpseclib v3 you're gonna need [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). Once you have that installed you can do `composer init` and then `composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:~3.0`.

By doing that you can replace this:

```php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
  header("Content-Type: text/plain");
  $sIncludePath = get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../inc/phpseclib';
  echo $sIncludePath."\n";
  set_include_path($sIncludePath);

  include('Crypt/Common/AsymmetricKey.php');
  include('Math/BigInteger.php');
  include('Crypt/EC.php');
  include('Crypt/PublicKeyLoader.php');
  include('Crypt/RSA.php');
```

With this:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Once you do that phpseclib v3 should work without a hitch. The issue you're having is due to the fact that phpseclib v3 is trying to autoload the engine, which it can't do because there's no autoloader.

Note that SSH is not required to use your resulting code once you have it working. To get PHPSecLib v3 to work for people without SSH, what you could do is locally do composer init and then composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:3.0 and then take your vendor directory and your composer.json and composer.lock file and put it into whatever project you want to. ie. end users wouldn't be running composer - you would be running composer. You would be downloading the dependencies and they'd just be using the dependencies you downloaded!

**Option 2: Use PHPSecLib2 Manually**

This option doesn't require SSH. PHPSecLib2 has less features than PHPSecLib3, however it's still actively maintained. (Even PHPSecLib1 receives regular updates.)

PHPSecLib2 doesn't have the PublicKeyLoader class, so you would use the RSA class instead as follows:

```
<?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
  header("Content-Type: text/plain");
  $sIncludePath = get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../s/phpseclib';
  echo $sIncludePath."\n";
  set_include_path($sIncludePath);

  include('Math/BigInteger.php');
  include('Crypt/RSA.php');
  include('Crypt/Hash.php');
  include('Crypt/Random.php');

  use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
  use phpseclib\Crypt\Hash;
  use phpseclib\Crypt\Random;

  function rsaEncryptionOaepSha256 ($publicKey, $plaintext) {
    $rsa = new RSA;
    $rsa->loadKey($publicKey);
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');
    $rsa->setMGFHash('sha256');
    return $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
  }

  function rsaDecryptionOaepSha256 ($privateKey, $ciphertext) {
    $rsa = new RSA;
    $rsa->loadKey($privateKey);
    $rsa->setHash('sha256');
    $rsa->setMGFHash('sha256');
    return $rsa->decrypt($ciphertext);
  }
  
  function loadRsaPrivateKeyPem() {
    // this is a sample key - don't worry !
    return '
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
';
  }

  function loadRsaPublicKeyPem() {
    // this is a sample key - don't worry !
    return '
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA8EmWJUZ/Osz4vXtUU2S+
0M4BP9+s423gjMjoX+qP1iCnlcRcFWxthQGN2CWSMZwR/vY9V0un/nsIxhZSWOH9
iKzqUtZD4jt35jqOTeJ3PCSr48JirVDNLet7hRT37Ovfu5iieMN7ZNpkjeIG/CfT
/QQl7R+kO/EnTmL3QjLKQNV/HhEbHS2/44x7PPoHqSqkOvl8GW0qtL39gTLWgAe8
01/w5PmcQ38CKG0oT2gdJmJqIxNmAEHkatYGHcMDtXRBpOhOSdraFj6SmPyHEmLB
ishaq7Jm8NPPNK9QcEQ3q+ERa5M6eM72PpF93g2p5cjKgyzzfoIV09Zb/LJ2aW2g
QwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
';
  }

  function base64Encoding ($input) {
    return base64_encode($input);
  }
  function base64Decoding ($input) {
    return base64_decode($input);
  }

  echo 'RSA 2048 encryption OAEP SHA-256 string' . PHP_EOL;
  $sDataToEncrypt = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  echo 'plaintext: ' . $sDataToEncrypt . PHP_EOL;

  // encryption
  echo PHP_EOL . '* * * encrypt the plaintext with the RSA public key * * *' .PHP_EOL;
  $ciphertextBase64 = base64Encoding(rsaEncryptionOaepSha256(loadRsaPublicKeyPem(), $sDataToEncrypt));
  echo 'ciphertextBase64: ' . $ciphertextBase64 . PHP_EOL;

  // transport the encrypted data to recipient

  // receiving the encrypted data, decryption
  echo PHP_EOL . '* * * decrypt the ciphertext with the RSA private key * * *' .PHP_EOL;
  $ciphertextReceivedBase64 = $ciphertextBase64;
  echo 'ciphertextReceivedBase64: ' . $ciphertextReceivedBase64 . PHP_EOL;
  $decryptedtext = rsaDecryptionOaepSha256(loadRsaPrivateKeyPem(), base64Decoding($ciphertextReceivedBase64));
  echo 'decryptedtext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

To manually downgrade to PHPSecLib2 and get the above code to work, you'll need to replace the phpseclib directory with the files located at this GitHub here: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0

Comment: So you're saying it's not possible? What does Composer do during the install and why couldn't it be done manually?

Comment: @azoundria - Well for one there are dependencies that are enumerated upon in composer.json but after that there's the autoloading of stuff. The biginteger engine is autoloaded, and for public keys, the plugins are all auto loaded and a lot of the ASN.1 maps are auto loaded to. There are like 100 or so ASN.1 maps. To manually include those instead of using an autoloader would be a ton of work. Now, you can do autoloading without composer but you still gotta manage the dependencies as well. phpseclib v2 doesn't have any other dependencies so all you'd need for that is an autoloader

Comment: @azoundria - and for v2 you can use Composer's autoloader without using all of Composer: http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/2.0.html For that matter, replacing Composer's autoloader with a generic PSR-4 autoloader would prob be sufficient. But v2 is also not nearly as autoload heavy as v3

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. However does v2 mean that it has significantly less features or functionality than v3 and may not be maintained going forward (such as newly uncovered security vulnerabilities)? Or is it more like a separate branch? Can composer be set up without a command line/SSH or is that the only way? I'm trying to create a solution that's going to work on all PHP hosting environments, including those without SSH access.

Comment: @azoundria - "_However does v2 mean that it has significantly less features or functionality than v3 and may not be maintained going forward (such as newly uncovered security vulnerabilities)?_" v1 is like 15 years old and is still getting updates. It had an update 5 days ago according to github. I don't think you have to worry about v2 being abandoned any time soon. As for less features...  yah v2 does have less features. v2 only supports RSA whereas v3 supports elliptic curves and DSA, etc

Comment: As for getting v3 to work for people without SSH....  it's def possible! What you could do is locally do `composer init` and then `composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:3.0` and then take your `vendor` directory and your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` file and put it into whatever project you want to. ie. end users wouldn't be running composer - _you_ would be running composer. _You_ would be downloading the dependencies and they'd just be using the dependencies you downloaded!

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at v3 for the future (and other features) but for now I'd like to get something working in v2 as I only really need RSA at the moment. I replaced the phpseclib with the v2 version and the PublicKeyLoader doesn't exist at all there. Do you have any idea how I could get the above code to work equivalently in v2? I'll have a bit more time to look at it much later tonight but if you know off-hand what I should be looking for or doing to downgrade the code to v2-compatible that would be super helpful.

Comment: @azoundria - https://pastebin.com/9arwu3TJ should do the trick! I didn't include anything after the phpseclib-specific code for brevity.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I got it working now and edited your answer to add all the information you provided which was super helpful. Once that edit is approved then I'll pick it as the chosen answer.